# Flash to trigger another flash

Tags: flash

Let's say we have two flash objects on the same html page. I want the first one to do some action and when it gets to the end to trigger the start of the second flash object in the page. One action in flash one to trigger another action into flash 2. Is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into the [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/local_connection_objects/) object

Comment: LocalConnection is the easier way in my opinion

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is use LocalConnection simplest and most common way to get it done. Another method would be to use Javacript, but that would be over kill.

Answer (score 1):

Tons of tutorials for this on Google: "[Flash Movies Communicate](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=flash+movies+communicate&aq=f&oq=flash+movies+communicate&aqi=&aq=f&oq=flash+movies+communicate&aqi=&fp=dMlfxuRvj0I)"

1. [An example of communication between Macromedia Flash 5 movies through JavaScript](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15692.html)
2. [Flash MX Tutorial - Movie to Movie Communication](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.minddrops.com%2FTutorials%2Fflashmx%2FMovieToMovie%2Fsender.html&ei=wddLSoGVL5Oetwf585G0DQ&rct=j&q=flash+movies+communicate&usg=AFQjCNGbFl_0YFtLCO5VZRPb4uflLBuc3Q)
3. [Communication between two movies](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/219/1/Communication-between-two-movies/Page1.html)
4. [Getting different Flash movies to talk to (and listen for) each other](http://www.pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=22)

Comment: Thank you very much, was not aware of LocalConnection.